# Make another column based using some values in other column

Tags: r

Table look like this and the `SampleID` and `Number` is the column names:

```
SampleID Number
G2Day2   15
G2Day4   11
G11Day13 5
```

I want to make another column using the values in the `SampleID`, so the new table will look like this:

```
SampleID Group Day Number
G2Day2   G2    2   15
G2Day4   G2    4   11
G11Day13 G11   13  5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` to split the `sampleID` and then `rbind` the resulting list together.

```
df[, c("Group", "Day")] <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df[, "SampleID"]), "Day"))
df[, c("SampleID", "Group", "Day", "Number")]
##   SampleID Group Day Number
## 1   G2Day2    G2   2     15
## 2   G2Day4    G2   4     11
## 3 G11Day13   G11  13      5
```

Comment: Thanks.It works. I just wonder if I want to split into two strings such as "G2" and "Day2", can strsplit do that?

Comment: Also, is there a way I can arrange the column order with typing out all the column name. I am just thinking if I have many columns in a file. It will take  a lot of works to write out the column names.

Comment: If you want to keep the "Day", I would use the `gsub` solution with `replacement = "Day"`. To rearrange, you can also use the column numbers (`df[, c(1,3,4,2)]`), but that can cause problems if you make changes later.

Answer (score 4):

`gsub` can do this particular task for you quite easily.  Try this:

```
df$Group <- gsub(pattern = "Day.*", replacement = "", x=df$SapmleID)
df$Number <- gsub(pattern = ".*Day", replacement = "", x=df$SampleID)
```

The .* is a regex that represents any number of characters

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tidyr` solution

```
library(tidyr)
cbind(df[1], separate(df, SampleID, c("Group", "Day"), "Day"))
#   SampleID Group Day Number
# 1   G2Day2    G2   2     15
# 2   G2Day4    G2   4     11
# 3 G11Day13   G11  13      5
```

Or similarly with `data.table` [v >= 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table) # v 1.9.5
setDT(df)[,  c("Group", "Day") := tstrsplit(as.character(SampleID), "Day")][]
#    SampleID Number Group Day
# 1:   G2Day2     15    G2   2
# 2:   G2Day4     11    G2   4
# 3: G11Day13      5   G11  13
```

Answer (score 1):

with a little regex:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="SampleID Number
G2Day2   15
G2Day4   11
G11Day13 5")

within(dat, {
  Group <- gsub('Day\\d+', '', SampleID)
  Day <- gsub('.*Day(.*)', '\\1', SampleID)
})

#   SampleID Number Day Group
# 1   G2Day2     15   2    G2
# 2   G2Day4     11   4    G2
# 3 G11Day13      5  13   G11
```

Answer (score -2):

If your new table already has the column names
something like this is what you would do.
Pseudo code here:

```
    foreach(Datarow row in myoriginaltable.rows)
    {
    int i = 0;
    // Get an index reference to the row you create and add to the new table
    i = myNewTable.AddRow(new DataRow);
```

myNewTable.Rows[i].Column["Number"] = row.Column["Number"];
// where ColumnName is the name of your column that you want to transfer from one to the other.
myNewTable.Rows[i].Column["ColumnName"] = row.Column["ColumnName"];

// Create a Column , give it a value from the row and Column["ColumnName"] 
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(row.Column["ColumnName"].Value.ToString());
myNewTable.Columns.Add(dc);
}
</code></pre>

Comment: what language are you speaking

Comment: This is C#, the question was to make a new column based on using values from a different column. This shows how to get that column from one and copy it to another column, he can get any values he wants.

Comment: The question is tagged with `r`, not `C#`; you're just adding complexity by introducing a second programming language to the issue